# p-value and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

(The p value) Which one of the statements about the p value is correct?
a) The p value is the predefined probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis is false. 
b) The p value is the estimated probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis is false. 
c) The p value is the estimated probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis is true. 
d) The p value is the predefined probability of making a mistake when the null hypothesis is true.
I am stuck between predefined and estimated.

Comment: It might be fair to distinguish the terms operationally like this: "predefined" means you could calculate the value without the data while any "estimated" value is based on the data.

Comment: Since we calculate the p value from our data, it will be estimated. So, would it be the answer C in this case?

Comment: You need to figure out the right choice yourself @NishaNidhi & the appropriate thing to do is to add the self study tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered your previous question, but this seems much more like homework or a test. I'll give you the definition and leave it up to you to answer based on the A-D answers. p-value is the probability of getting a test-statistic equal to or larger than the 1 calculated for that data at hand, given the data, model assumed, and assuming the null-hypothesis is true. Change your data, model, assumptions or even test-statistic, you change the p-value.

edited: Typo.

Comment: One might take issue with the generality of this characterization, especially the term "large."  See [the example I posted in our thread on p-values.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/130772/919)  A historically notable counterexample is Fisher's re-analysis of Mendel's experimental data on peas, where the relevant p-value was computed by the chance the test statistic would be *smaller than or equal to* the observed statistic.  See, for instance, section 4.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.2975.pdf.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. "Large" was a typo, meant larger. Did mean to also say equal to or larger than. Thanks for pointing out the opposite though! I had never seen that before.

Comment: @Kunio A more precise definition would be "at least as extreme", since in many cases, significance can mean both sufficiently greater than, or less than the null.